# How to read or parse MHTML (.mht) files in java

Tags: java, parsing, compression, mime, mhtml

I need to mine the **content** of most of known document files like:

1. pdf
2. html
3. doc/docx etc.

For most of these file formats I am planning to use:

http://tika.apache.org/

But as of now `Tika` does not support MHTML (*.mht) files.. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML )
There are few examples in C# ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx ) but I found none in Java.

I tried opening the *.mht file in 7Zip and it failed...Although the WinZip was able to decompress the file into images and text (CSS, HTML, Script) as text and binary files...

As per MSDN page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767785%28VS.85%29.aspx#compress_content ) and the `code project` page i mentioned earlier ... mht files use GZip compression ....

Attempting to decompress in java results in following exceptions:
With `java.uti.zip.GZIPInputStream`

```
java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at GZipTest.main(GZipTest.java:16)
```

And with `java.util.zip.ZipFile`

```
 java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at GZipTest.main(GZipTest.java:21)
```

Kindly suggest how to decompress it....

Thanks....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Frankly, I wasn't expecting a solution in near future and was about to give up, but some how I stumbled on this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527355%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx

Although, not a very catchy in first look. But if you look carefully you will get clue. After reading this I fired up my IE and at random started saving pages as `*.mht` file. Let me go line by line...

But let me explain beforehand that my ultimate goal was to separate/extract out the `html` content and parse it... the solution is not complete in itself as it depends on the `character set` or `encoding` I choose while saving. But even though it will extract the individual files with minor hitches...

I hope this will be useful for anyone who is trying to parse/decompress `*.mht/MHTML` files :)

======= Explanation ========
** Taken from a mht file **

```
From: "Saved by Windows Internet Explorer 7"
```

It is the software used for saving the file

```
Subject: Google
Date: Tue, 13 Jul 2010 21:23:03 +0530
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Subject, date and mime-version … much like the mail format

```
  Content-Type: multipart/related;
type="text/html";
```

This is the part which tells us that it is a `multipart` document. A multipart document has one or more different sets of data combined in a single body, a `multipart` Content-Type field must appear in the entity's header. Here, we can also see the type as `"text/html"`.

```
boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0007_01CB22D1.93BBD1A0"
```

Out of all this is the most important part. This is the unique delimiter which divides two different parts (html,images,css,script etc). **Once** you get hold of this, everything gets easy... Now, I just have to iterate through the document and finding out different sections and saving them as per their `Content-Transfer-Encoding` (base64, quoted-printable etc) ...
    .
    .
    .

**SAMPLE**

```
 ------=_NextPart_000_0007_01CB22D1.93BBD1A0
 Content-Type: text/html;
 charset="utf-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
 Content-Location: http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8

 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" =
.
.
.
```

** JAVA CODE **

An interface for defining constants.

```
public interface IConstants 
{
    public String BOUNDARY = "boundary";
    public String CHAR_SET = "charset";
    public String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
    public String CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING = "Content-Transfer-Encoding";
    public String CONTENT_LOCATION = "Content-Location";

    public String UTF8_BOM = "=EF=BB=BF";

    public String UTF16_BOM1 = "=FF=FE";
    public String UTF16_BOM2 = "=FE=FF";
}
```

The main parser class...

```
/**
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 */
package com.test.mht.core;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

/**
 * File to parse and decompose *.mts file in its constituting parts.
 * @author Manish Shukla 
 */

public class MHTParser implements IConstants
{
    private File mhtFile;
    private File outputFolder;

    public MHTParser(File mhtFile, File outputFolder) {
        this.mhtFile = mhtFile;
        this.outputFolder = outputFolder;
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void decompress() throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String type = "";
        String encoding = "";
        String location = "";
        String filename = "";
        String charset = "utf-8";
        StringBuilder buffer = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mhtFile));

            final String boundary = getBoundary(reader);
            if(boundary == null)
                throw new Exception("Failed to find document 'boundary'... Aborting");

            String line = null;
            int i = 1;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String temp = line.trim();
                if(temp.contains(boundary)) 
                {
                    if(buffer != null) {
                        writeBufferContentToFile(buffer,encoding,filename,charset);
                        buffer = null;
                    }

                    buffer = new StringBuilder();
                }else if(temp.startsWith(CONTENT_TYPE)) {
                    type = getType(temp);
                }else if(temp.startsWith(CHAR_SET)) {
                    charset = getCharSet(temp);
                }else if(temp.startsWith(CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING)) {
                    encoding = getEncoding(temp);
                }else if(temp.startsWith(CONTENT_LOCATION)) {
                    location = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(":")+1).trim();
                    i++;
                    filename = getFileName(location,type);
                }else {
                    if(buffer != null) {
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }

        }finally 
        {
            if(null != reader)
                reader.close();
        }

    }

    private String getCharSet(String temp) 
    {
        String t = temp.split("=")[1].trim();
        return t.substring(1, t.length()-1);
    }

    /**
     * Save the file as per character set and encoding 
     */
    private void writeBufferContentToFile(StringBuilder buffer,String encoding, String filename, String charset) 
    throws Exception
    {

        if(!outputFolder.exists())
            outputFolder.mkdirs();

        byte[] content = null; 

        boolean text = true;

        if(encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("base64")){
            content = getBase64EncodedString(buffer);
            text = false;
        }else if(encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("quoted-printable")) {
            content = getQuotedPrintableString(buffer);         
        }
        else
            content = buffer.toString().getBytes();

        if(!text)
        {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try
            {
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                bos.write(content);
                bos.flush();
            }finally {
                bos.close();
            }
        }else 
        {
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try
            {
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), charset));
                bw.write(new String(content));
                bw.flush();
            }finally {
                bw.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * When the save the *.mts file with 'utf-8' encoding then it appends '=EF=BB=BF'</br>
     * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
     */
    private byte[] getQuotedPrintableString(StringBuilder buffer) 
    {
        //Set<String> uniqueHex = new HashSet<String>();
        //final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(=\\p{XDigit}{2})*");

        String temp = buffer.toString().replaceAll(UTF8_BOM, "").replaceAll("=\n", "");

        //Matcher m = p.matcher(temp);
        //while(m.find()) {
        //  uniqueHex.add(m.group());
        //}

        //System.out.println(uniqueHex);

        //for (String hex : uniqueHex) {
            //temp = temp.replaceAll(hex, getASCIIValue(hex.substring(1)));
        //}     

        return temp.getBytes();
    }

    /*private String getASCIIValue(String hex) {
        return ""+(char)Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    }*/
    /**
     * Although system dependent..it works well
     */
    private byte[] getBase64EncodedString(StringBuilder buffer) throws Exception {
        return new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(buffer.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Tries to get a qualified file name. If the name is not apparent it tries to guess it from the URL.
     * Otherwise it returns 'unknown.<type>'
     */
    private String getFileName(String location, String type) 
    {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w|_|-)+\\.\\w+");
        String ext = "";
        String name = "";
        if(type.toLowerCase().endsWith("jpeg"))
            ext = "jpg";
        else
            ext = type.split("/")[1];

        if(location.endsWith("/")) {
            name = "main";
        }else
        {
            name = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
            String fname = "";
            while(m.find()) {
                fname = m.group();
            }

            if(fname.trim().length() == 0)
                name = "unknown";
            else
                return getUniqueName(fname.substring(0,fname.indexOf(".")), fname.substring(fname.indexOf(".") + 1, fname.length()));
        }
        return getUniqueName(name,ext);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a qualified unique output file path for the parsed path.</br>
     * In case the file already exist it appends a numarical value a continues
     */
    private String getUniqueName(String name,String ext)
    {
        int i = 1;
        File file = new File(outputFolder,name + "." + ext);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            while(true)
            {
                file = new File(outputFolder, name + i + "." + ext);
                if(!file.exists())
                    return file.getAbsolutePath();
                i++;
            }
        }

        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private String getType(String line) {
        return splitUsingColonSpace(line);
    }

    private String getEncoding(String line){
        return splitUsingColonSpace(line);
    }

    private String splitUsingColonSpace(String line) {
        return line.split(":\\s*")[1].replaceAll(";", "");
    }

    /**
     * Gives you the boundary string
     */
    private String getBoundary(BufferedReader reader) throws Exception 
    {
        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.trim();
            if(line.startsWith(BOUNDARY)) {
                return line.substring(line.indexOf("\"") + 1, line.lastIndexOf("\""));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I have a question though: How do you determine the end of a section HEADER? I mean, the section starts with the boundary defined somewhere above, then there come header stuff like type/encoding/location etc, and after this it seems to me that every header is delimited by ASCII 0D0A0D0A (two times CR+LF). Am I right about this, or is there any other guaranteed delimiter?

Comment: @favonius: Does your code converts the .mht file to html?

Comment: @UmeshKumar : The code was for data extraction. But i think it should be straightforward to convert mht to html. Google around may be a library already exist.

Comment: I tried using this solution and initially it worked, but soon I noticed big problems. Note that BufferedReader.readLine() methods assumes UTF-8 encoding and converts original input bytes to Java 16-bit characters, re-encoding per UTF-8 specs. So if you have a binary file, even an HTML file with transfer-encoding "binary" and a different character encoding in HTML (I had Shift_JIS as a test sample), all hell gets lose. Ended up implementing my own MHTML (MIME) decoder from scratch in C++, and accessing it from Java with JNI.

Answer (score 3):

A more compact code using Java Mail APIs

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class MhtParser {

    private File mhtFile;
    private File outputFolder;

    public MhtParser(File mhtFile, File outputFolder) {
        this.mhtFile = mhtFile;
        this.outputFolder = outputFolder;
    }

    public void decompress() throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = 
            new MimeMessage(
                    Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null),
                    new FileInputStream(mhtFile));

        if (message.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
            outputFolder.mkdir();
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();

            for (int i = 0; i < mimeMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
                String fileName = bodyPart.getFileName();

                if (fileName == null) {
                    String[] locationHeader = bodyPart.getHeader("Content-Location");
                    if (locationHeader != null && locationHeader.length > 0) {
                        fileName = 
                            new File(new URL(locationHeader[0]).getFile()).getName();
                    }
                }

                if (fileName != null) {
                    FileOutputStream out = 
                        new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFolder, fileName));

                    IOUtils.copy(bodyPart.getInputStream(), out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this code, but have stuck on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76744757/parsing-mht-mhtml-file-message-getcontent-failed) error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do it on you own.

With dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Roll you mht file

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MessageTree.main(new String[]{"YOU MHT FILE PATH"});
}
```

`MessageTree` will

```
/**
 * Displays a parsed Message in a window. The window will be divided into
 * two panels. The left panel displays the Message tree. Clicking on a
 * node in the tree shows information on that node in the right panel.
 *
 * Some of this code have been copied from the Java tutorial's JTree section.
 */
```

Then you can look into it.

;-)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but expanding on [@wener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870054/wener)'s answer for anyone else stumbling across this.

The [Apache Mime4J](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/) library seems to have the most readily accessible solution for [EML or MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) processing, much easier than rolling-your-own!

My prototype '`parseMhtToFile`' function below rips html files and other artifacts out of a Cognos active report 'mht' file, but could be tailored to other purposes.

This is written in Groovy and requires [Apache Mime4J 'core' and 'dom' jars](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/start/download.html) (currently 0.7.2).

```
import org.apache.james.mime4j.dom.Message
import org.apache.james.mime4j.dom.Multipart
import org.apache.james.mime4j.dom.field.ContentTypeField
import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.DefaultMessageBuilder
import org.apache.james.mime4j.stream.MimeConfig

/**
 * Use Mime4J MessageBuilder to parse an mhtml file (assumes multipart) into
 * separate html files.
 * Files will be written to outDir (or parent) as baseName + partIdx + ext.
 */
void parseMhtToFile(File mhtFile, File outDir = null) {
    if (!outDir) {outDir = mhtFile.parentFile }
    // File baseName will be used in generating new filenames
    def mhtBaseName = mhtFile.name.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')

    // -- Set up Mime parser, using Default Message Builder
    MimeConfig parserConfig  = new MimeConfig();
    parserConfig.setMaxHeaderLen(-1); // The default is a mere 10k
    parserConfig.setMaxLineLen(-1); // The default is only 1000 characters.
    parserConfig.setMaxHeaderCount(-1); // Disable the check for header count.
    DefaultMessageBuilder builder = new DefaultMessageBuilder();
    builder.setMimeEntityConfig(parserConfig);

    // -- Parse the MHT stream data into a Message object
    println "Parsing ${mhtFile}...";
    InputStream mhtStream = mhtFile.newInputStream()
    Message message = builder.parseMessage(mhtStream);

    // -- Process the resulting body parts, writing to file
    assert message.getBody() instanceof Multipart
    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getBody();
    def parts = multipart.getBodyParts();
    parts.eachWithIndex { p, i ->
        ContentTypeField cType = p.header.getField('content-type')
        println "${p.class.simpleName}\t${i}\t${cType.mimeType}"

        // Assume mime sub-type is a "good enough" file-name extension 
        // e.g. text/html = html, image/png = png, application/json = json
        String partFileName = "${mhtBaseName}_${i}.${cType.subType}"
        File partFile = new File(outDir, partFileName)

        // Write part body stream to file
        println "Writing ${partFile}...";
        if (partFile.exists()) partFile.delete();
        InputStream partStream = p.body.inputStream;
        partFile.append(partStream);
    }
}
```

Usage is simply:

```
File mhtFile = new File('<path>', 'Report-en-au.mht')
parseMhtToFile(mhtFile)
println 'Done.'
```

Output is:

```
Parsing <path>\Report-en-au.mht...
BodyPart    0   text/html
Writing <path>\Report-en-au_0.html...
BodyPart    1   image/png
Writing <path>\Report-en-au_1.png...
Done.
```

Thoughts on other improvements:

- For ['text' mime parts](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/dom/TextBody.html), you can access a [`Reader`](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/dom/TextBody.html#getReader()) instead of a `Stream` which might be more appropriate for text mining as the OP requested.
- For generated filename extensions, I'd use another library to lookup appropriate extension, not assume the mime sub-type is adequate.
- Handle Single-body (non-Multipart) and Recursive Multipart mhtml files and other complexities. These may require a [MimeStreamParser](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/parser/MimeStreamParser.html) with custom [Content Handler](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/parser/AbstractContentHandler.html) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

U can try http://www.chilkatsoft.com/mht-features.asp , it can pack/unpack and you can handle it after as normal files. The download link is: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp

Comment: Thanks Roki.. I have seen the chilkatsoft offerings but couldn't use it because:
1. It is coming as a native implementation `chilkat.dll` .. I require something which is written in pure java.
2. It is a commercial product.. and in my project i am using open source products... :o

Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i was used http://jtidy.sourceforge.net to parse/read/index mht files (but as normal files, not compressed files)

Comment: Thanks Wajdy Essam... Most of the *.mht files are saved from IE using `save as` option... and by default they are compressed... But still i will try `jtidy` ...