# Convert docx/pptx to MHTML in pura java

Tags: java, ms-word, powerpoint, mhtml, docx4j

I am struggling to convert word documents and power point presentations to convert to HTML/MHTML pages.
I am able to convert docs to html using docx4j but it comes out as distorted and creates images etc as separate files (standard HTML).

I have a requirement where users upload docx and pptx files and then I can show them the output HTML in web browser. So I need a single *.mht file output from document.
The kind of output generated by MS word aby saving file as mht is great. I want similar function but in pure java only.

I will deploy the service on Linux so can't even call native commands of Ms Office.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are the "distort"ions of which you speak?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to read or parse MHTML (.mht) files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230305/how-to-read-or-parse-mhtml-mht-files-in-java) as a starting point.