# Issue parsing MHTML

Tags: java, html, parsing, specifications, mhtml

I was able to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230305/how-to-read-or-parse-mhtml-mht-files-in-java) as a starting point in parsing an "mht" file but the "3D" in the anchor tags (e.g.: `<a href=3D"[my anchor]">[anchor text]></a>`) breaks all the internal links and embedded images. I can have the parser replace "=3D" with just "=" (e.g.: `<a href="[my anchor]">[anchor text]></a>`) and it appears to work fine but I want to understand the purpose of that "meta markup".

Why does exporting from ".docx" to ".mht" add "3D" to the right-hand sides of most (if not all) of the html attributes? Is there a better way to handle them or a better regex to use when replacing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `=3D` is a result of [quoted printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). It shouldn't be too hard to find a java library for decoding quoted printable data.

Comment: Specifically, the regex I described in my question replaces a quoted printable encoding of '=' with '='. I'm going to look into decoding other quoted printable encoded characters. Thanks again!