# Sending HTML emails with spring integration

Tags: html-email, spring-integration

I am using spring integration for a process which ends in an email being sent.

However, it is an HTML email and I receive the source for it, not the rendered HTML.

I have tried to use the mail header enricher provided with *spring-integration-mail 2.1.4* to set the *content type* or activate *multipart* without result.

*Can it be done with the mail header enricher or is it supposed to be configured in some other way?*

A pure XML configuration preferable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read or parse MHTML (.mht) files in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230305/how-to-read-or-parse-mhtml-mht-files-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send HTML via the XML configuration, you just need to set the content type as you said via the header enricher, example code below.

```
<int-mail:header-enricher id="emailheaderenricher">
        <int-mail:content-type value="text/html;"/>
        <int-mail:subject value="a subject"/>
        <int-mail:to value="mail@somewhere.org"/>
        <int-mail:from value="from@example.org"/>
</int-mail:header-enricher>
```