# Convert Text to HTML in Android

Tags: android, html, text

I'm looking for ways to convert text with spaces and symbols in html in android,

**For Example:**

```
"Hi this is my text" to "Hi%20this%20is%20my%20text"
```

Also with symbols...

Anyone knows any easy way to do it?

What I find is to convert html text to plain text.

Thanks in Advance......

Comment: This is NOT html. This is just URL encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is not HTML but URL encoding, use `URLEncoder.encode`, see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

For example, if your write

```
String s = URLEncoder.encode("Hi this is my text", "UTF-8");
```

variable `s` will contain `Hi%20this%20is%20my%20text`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky no, first of all, this is still URL, not HTML encoding. MHT files contain the archive of a web page in MIME format, so converting it require something that could parse that, which includes some browsers. If you want to do it programmatically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230305/how-to-read-or-parse-mhtml-mht-files-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextUtils.htmlEncode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode%28java.lang.String%29) for this purpose.