# Parsing mht (mhtml) file message.getContent() failed

Tags: java, android, mhtml

The following code inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58623351/653379) should take a file in (.mht/.mhtml) format and
convert it to html format.

The mht file is a file saved from chrome browser to the `Download` directory.

The code failes when `message.getContent()` is called.
How can I fix it?

```
// MainActivity.java
package org.xralf.safreading;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class MhtParser {

        //private File mhtFile;
        private String mhtFile;
        private File outputFolder;

        public MhtParser(String mhtFile, File outputFolder) {
            this.mhtFile = mhtFile;
            this.outputFolder = outputFolder;
        }

        public void decompress() throws Exception {
            MimeMessage message =
                    new MimeMessage(
                            Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null),
                            //new FileInputStream(mhtFile));
                            //new ByteArrayInputStream(mhtFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                            IOUtils.toInputStream(mhtFile,  StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            //mhtFile);

            if (message.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
                outputFolder.mkdir();
                MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();

                for (int i = 0; i < mimeMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
                    String fileName = bodyPart.getFileName();

                    if (fileName == null) {
                        String[] locationHeader = bodyPart.getHeader("Content-Location");
                        if (locationHeader != null && locationHeader.length > 0) {
                            fileName =
                                    new File(new URL(locationHeader[0]).getFile()).getName();
                        }
                    }

                    if (fileName != null) {
                        FileOutputStream out =
                                new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFolder, fileName));

                        IOUtils.copy(bodyPart.getInputStream(), out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startOpenForResult =
            registerForActivityResult(
                    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                Intent data = result.getData();
                                if (data != null) {
                                    Uri currentUri = data.getData();
                                    try {
                                        String content = readFileContent(currentUri);
                                        editText.setText(content);

                                        File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "dir");
                                        MhtParser mhtParser = new MhtParser(content, directory);
                                        try {
                                            mhtParser.decompress();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startOpenForResult.launch(intent);

            }
        });
    }
    private String readFileContent(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //stringBuilder.append(currentLine).append("\n");
            stringBuilder.append(currentLine);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}


// activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="242dp"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="read"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the error from `logcat`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: org.xralf.safreading, PID: 7062
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;
                                                                                                        at org.xralf.safreading.MainActivity$MhtParser.decompress(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                                                        at org.xralf.safreading.MainActivity$1.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:112)
                                                                                                        at org.xralf.safreading.MainActivity$1.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:98)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:149)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:68)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$LifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPostStarted(ReportFragment.java:187)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityPostStarted(Activity.java:1380)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8113)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/org.xralf.safreading/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~i4aHJ3VUmdawPwuyNI_dHg==/org.xralf.safreading-rH4ceYka7KTyjpEojS3MzQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~i4aHJ3VUaddwPwuyNI_dHg==/org.xralf.safreading-rH4MeYkr7KTyjpEajS3MzQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at org.xralf.safreading.MainActivity$MhtParser.decompress(MainActivity.java:54) 
                                                                                                        at org.xralf.safreading.MainActivity$1.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:112) 
                                                                                                        at org.xralf.safreading.MainActivity$1.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:98) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:149) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:68) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$LifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPostStarted(ReportFragment.java:187) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityPostStarted(Activity.java:1380) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8113) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```